# What does the HTTP response status "200 Filtered" mean?

Tags: http

I have a website where some CSS files aren't being served to the browser, and when I open up Firebug's Net panel, the response is "200 Filtered" (see image).

I know what 200 normally means, but I haven't been able to find what 200 Filtered refers to, i.e. the actual content isn't being served, but instead, when you try to view the resource directly in the browser, an "unavailable" page is displayed.

I would just like to know what this status really means.

[image: Screenshot of Firebug Net panel]

Comment: You probably have some proxy in your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP status code "200" means the request is successfully handled by the Server, and "200 OK" is standard HTTP status code, some possible reasons:
1. HTTP Server with some filter rules and return "200 Filtered".
2. Some proxies filter something with changing status code "200 OK" to "200 Filtered".
3. Cache Server filter some resource and return "200 Filtered".